# getting an error massage "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" in debian

Tags: debian, linux, installation

I am trying to install java in my debian server but when I am running any of these command getting an error massage every time that is -

```
insserv: Starting tomcat depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service resolvconf at depth 10
insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 8
insserv: There is a loop between service tomcat and checkroot if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and mountdevsubfs if started
insserv: There is a loop between service tomcat and resolvconf if started
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing x11-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 exim4-base
 exim4-daemon-light
 exim4
 avahi-daemon
 libnss-mdns
 x11-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using these command-

```
apt-get upgrade --show-upgraded
apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Is any one know how can I solve this problem? Thx

Comment: try to update your repos by : apt-get update and then try to fix some old installs that seems to be broken with : apt-get install -f

Comment: I tried still its not giving error massage.

Comment: I guess you mean an error message. I have no idea about what might be an "error massage" but it would certainly be off topic in serverfault ;-)

Comment: I am getting "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" error so I think its not the off topic of serverfault.

Comment: "Message" with an "E" and Massage with an "A" are quite different words.

Comment: different words means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the script generating the error under `/var/lib/dpkg/info`; it will probably be named `avahi-daemon.postinst`.

**Dangerous:** if you really know what you are doing, you can try commenting out the line(s) which generate the error and try configuring the packages again with

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: not following which line I would need to comment.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and to solve it, I just deleted the current Avahi config

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon
```

If it doesn't exist try avahi-daemon.dpkg-new instead of avahi-daemon

I then just ran the install

```
sudo apt-get -f install avahi-daemon
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So something is wrong with the LSB header in `/etc/init.d/avahi-daemon`.  I would suspect it is because that file has be modified, preventing you from getting the current packaged version of this file.  What I'd have you check is to compare what dpkg thinks the current version of this file is, with the version you actually have in the file system.  This command will tell you what the current packaged version is:

```
dpkg -s avahi-daemon | grep /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon
```

This should return an md5sum something like this:

```
/etc/init.d/avahi-daemon 3c6d0943a969795d08675ad16ac74f62
```

Compare that to the version you currently have by running `md5sum /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon`.  If this sum differs than the one returned by dpkg, this is, in fact, the problem.  If so, you can correct it by telling dpkg to overwrite all of the conffiles for the avahi-daemon package with the following command:

```
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confnew" --reinstall install avahi-daemon
```

After this, try runngin `dpkg --configure -a ; apt-get -f install` to complete the pending actions.

Note that this will overwrite all the configuration for avahi.  If you have some customization you need to save, we can talk about how to do that.

If the md5sums DID match, then please post the LSB header from the top of `/etc/init.d/avahi-daemon` and tell us what version is reported by `dpkg -l avahi-daemon`

Comment: I have checked both are same by first command means by "dpkg" I am getting 
====> /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon 619eb9412486f8e39c309bcbe128950d
and by second command means by "md5sum" I am getting 
====>619eb9412486f8e39c309bcbe128950d  /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon
So I am thinking both are same

Comment: what version of avahi-daemon is installed?

Comment: how may I check this?